# How to test reliability of my Veins simulations?

Tags: omnet++, inet, veins

I am developing Car2X applications in order to simulate case studies based on Veins framework.

As an Information Systems student, I have been worried mostly about the code of my applications.

Recently I noticed that VEINS has no LLC, NETWORK and TRANSPORT layers in its source code (/src).

My question is: how to assure that my simulation runs would generate data close to reality for Car2X applications when there's none of these layers above in the source code?

P.S.: I am aware of INET framework and its protocols, I was just wondering if I could use just Veins for my case studies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers you mentioned are not needed for most Car2X simulations. If you download, for example, Veins 4.4, you will find only simulation models for single hop broadcast transmission of frames, the most general use case. If you want to simulate a special protocol, say, for multi-hop transmission of frames, you will need to implement this as a network layer. Then, your simulation will have a network layer model.

Comment: ... and if you need something more detailed, have a look at [artery](https://github.com/riebl/artery), which is a pretty huge package that implements significant parts of the European standards wrt. message exchange formats and so on.

Comment: Right - forgot to mention that there are many module libraries that extend Veins with more protocol models. As a further example, there is also [ArteryLTE](https://github.com/ibr-cm/artery-lte), which combines Artery with Veins LTE. Lastly, of course Veins can also be linked with [the INET Framework](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet), which offers a wealth of simulation models for "standard" Internet protocols.